# Query data in MongoDB vs Filtering in Code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This question is performance based.

If I have a collection which I want to query on multiple fields (fieldValue < x < fieldValue, status = 'pending' etc...) is it better to query via a mongoDB query or rather to retrieve a sample of the collection that fits some simpler query such as status = 'pending' and then do further filtering of the data in the server code?

When would you recommend which approach and when not?

Thank you for your taking your time.

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 0):

Go for single query option, since the filtering most of the unwanted data and fetching the required data from the Database should be done in the Database itself. Any additional operations will take its own time and resources to complete the same job. Here in this case we can use [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/), [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/), [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/). Performance will be high if the data is operated at the Data layer itself.

**Sample Collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7e08e1b021d0f556c29"), "value" : 10, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7e58e1b021d0f556c2a"), "value" : 20, "status" : "completed" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7e88e1b021d0f556c2b"), "value" : 40, "status" : "In Progress" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7ec8e1b021d0f556c2c"), "value" : 50, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7f08e1b021d0f556c2d"), "value" : 750, "status" : "completed" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7f68e1b021d0f556c2e"), "value" : 90, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7fb8e1b021d0f556c2f"), "value" : 190, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7fe8e1b021d0f556c30"), "value" : 120, "status" : "completed" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c8038e1b021d0f556c31"), "value" : 220, "status" : "completed" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c8078e1b021d0f556c32"), "value" : 720, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c80b8e1b021d0f556c33"), "value" : 7420, "status" : "In Progress" }
```

> Sample Query: 20 < x < 300 and status = pending

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{value:{$gt: 20}, value:{$lt:300}, status:{$eq:"pending"}}]})
```

The result will be

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7e08e1b021d0f556c29"), "value" : 10, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7ec8e1b021d0f556c2c"), "value" : 50, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7f68e1b021d0f556c2e"), "value" : 90, "status" : "pending" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c7fb8e1b021d0f556c2f"), "value" : 190, "status" : "pending" }
```

Hope it helps!